# How to collapse all nodes except the selected branch?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I collapse all nodes except the branch currently selected?

Here's what I've got

```
    private void treeview1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode node = e.Node;
        treeView1.CollapseAll();
        while (node.Parent != null)
        {
            node.Expand();
            node = node.Parent;
        }
    }
```

Root node collapses regardless. If I expand I can see the child item is expanded sometimes.
In the perfect world if I select a node it immediately expands, and any node outside this branch is collapsed. With the way I'm trying to do it now I wouldn't be able to use e.Node.Expand(); at the beginning either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to expand just one branch of the same level, handle the `TreeView.AfterExpand` event to collapse the *neighbor* nodes:

```cs
private void treeView1_AfterExpand(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    // If you need to exclude the root nodes, return if the e.Node.Parent == null.
    var nodes = e.Node.Parent == null ? treeView1.Nodes : e.Node.Parent.Nodes;

    if (nodes.Count > 1)
        foreach (var tn in nodes
            .Cast<TreeNode>()
            .Where(n => n != e.Node && n.IsExpanded))
            tn.Collapse();
}
```

To *auto* expand a node (especially when the `TreeView.ShowPlusMinus` property is disabled), handle the `TreeView.AfterSelect` event to expand the selected node:

```cs
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0 && !e.Node.IsExpanded) e.Node.Expand();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.